# How can I set the url prefix of the rabbitmq management plugin

Tags: http, plugins, rabbitmq, prefix

the http interface of management plugin uses the following awkward prefix:

```
http://myserver:15672/#/
```

how can i change the '#' to  a prefix like "madmin", so that the url would like

```
http://myserver:15672/madmin/
```

Comment: Why not simply `http://myserver:15672`

Comment: because it will sit behind a firewall, which will use an nginx proxy to forward it to the "real" myserver:15672. No traffic over http to the outside.